# Removing anonymous listener in componentWillUnmoint

Tags: reactjs

I would like to remove a click listener inside my react component. Is this a valid code ?
(btw: I'm not using 'bind' inside this project at all. )

```
componentDidMount() {
window.addEventListener('click', () => console log('all selected elements should be removed now!'));
}


componentWillUnmount() {
window.removeEventListener('click', () => console log('all selected elements 
should be removed now!'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addEventListner` and `removeEventListeners` need to both use the same reference for the handler and hence an anonymous function won't work.

According to eventListener documentation:

> The event listener to be removed is identified using a combination of
>   the event type, the event listener function itself, and various
>   optional options that may affect the matching process

You need to use the same function reference while adding and removing listener

```
handleClick = () =>{
   console log('all selected elements should be removed now!');
}
componentDidMount() { window.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick) }

componentWillUnmount() { window.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick); }
```

Comment: Thanks Shubkham! I was wondering what does this do if any: window.removeEventListener('click'); is that removing any listener?